# Python Celery: Updating the state of an AsyncResult

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

After a parent task succeeds, depending on some of his child tasks results, I wish to update the task state.

However:
1/ I cannot find a way to retrieve the actual task instance based on its id, only its AsyncResult

```
def level5_success(task_id):
  result = app.AsyncResult(task_id)
  # Set the parent task state (do not work)
  app.AsyncResult(task_id).update_state(state='HOWAREYOUDOING')
```

2/ I cannot find a way to update the state of an AsyncResult, only with the task itself using update_state:

```
def on_level4_success(sender, *args, **kwargs):
  sender.update_state(state='HOWAREYOUDOING')
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It feels like you are operating outside the bounds of what celery is designed to do.  Coordination of work state and process is supposed to be done with the [worker canvas](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html), not by monkeying around with the celery internals.  Even if you manage to get it to work, I doubt that state hacking is in the contract celery intends to keep with its API; it is entirely possible that your work will be broken by future changes to celery.

What are you trying to do that you cannot do with groups, chords and chains?

Comment: Well, maybe it's a design problem. I have different levels of tasks launched asynchronously. The lowest level performs one api call to the twitter api. On success, depending on the remaining available calls (due to twitter API limits), either I send another subtask immediately, or I wait 15 minutes (time for the API limits to be raised) or everything was extracted so the job is finished.
But the use of on_success signals prevents me from using chains. That's my problem.

Comment: It sounds like dynamic rescheduling with things like [countdown](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html?highlight=countdown#eta-and-countdown) would address your use case.  In particular, you hit the twitter api and have an if case that either reschedules a task immediately, reschedules with a countdown, or does whatever clearout you need.  If you need to share data between tasks, you might pass a config object.